# 1, 2, 3, 14... or is it 15?

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory, primes

A well known [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98W9QuMq-2k) by the Irish rock band [U2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U2) starts with the singer Bono saying "1, 2, 3, 14" in Spanish ("*uno, dos, tres, catorce*").

There are [various](http://forum.atu2.com/index.php?topic=4695.30) [theories](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Bono-sing-Uno-Dos-Tres-Catorce-in-Vertigo?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) as to the significance of those numbers. Apparently the [official explanation](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Bono-sing-Uno-Dos-Tres-Catorce-in-Vertigo/answer/Matias-Petroccello) is "*we drank too much that night*". But there's a more interesting hypothesis: Bono is referring to some integer sequence from OEIS, such as

[**A107083**](https://oeis.org/A107083):

> Integers `k` such that `10^k + 31` is prime. 
>   `1`, `2`, `3`, `14`, `18`, `44`, `54`, ...

In an interview, when asked the inevitable question "why 14", Bono admitted he was a bit tired of that number. The journalist suggested "15" instead, and in that night's concert the lyrics were indeed changed into "1, 2, 3, 15". (The story can be read [here](https://www.elconfidencialdigital.com/opinion/tribuna-libre/catorce/20050519000000104195.html), in Spanish). Quite likely the journalist took inspiration from

[**A221860**](https://oeis.org/A221860):

> Indices `k` such that `prime(k) - k` is a power of `2`, where `prime(k)` is the `k`-th prime. 
>   `1`, `2`, `3`, `15`, `39`, `2119`, `4189897`, ...

## The challenge

Write two programs in the same language. The first should take an input `n` and output the `n`-th term of [A107083](https://oeis.org/A107083), or the first `n` terms. Similarly, the second should output the `n`-th term of [A221860](https://oeis.org/A221860), or the first `n` terms.

The **score** is the **sum** of **lengths** of the two programs, in bytes, plus the **square** of the [**Levenshtein distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the byte representations of the two programs.

If a character encoding is used such that each character corresponds to one byte, [this script](https://planetcalc.com/1721/) can be used to measure Levenshtein distance.

For example, if the two programs are `abcdefgh` and `bcdEEfg`, the score is `8 + 7 + 4^2 = 31`.

Lowest score wins.

## Aditional rules

- The output can be `1`-based or `0`-based, independently for each sequence (so it is allowed if one of the programs is `1`-based and the other is `0`-based).
- Each program can, consistently but independently of the other, either output the `n`-th term or the first `n` terms.
- Programs or functions are allowed, independently for each sequence.
- Input and output means and format are [flexible as usual](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 + 16 + 1² = 33

#### A107083

```
⁵*+31ÆḍÆNB>/
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41YtbWPDw20Pd/QebvNzstPnMjzcrvz//39TAA)

#### A221860

```
⁵*+31ÆạÆNB>/
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41YtbWPDw20Pdy083ObnZKfPZXi4Xfn///@mAA)

#### How it works

```
1Ç#           Main link. Argument: n

1             Set the return value to 1.
 Ç#           Call the helper link with arguments k, k + 1, k + 2, ... until n of
              them return a truthy value. Return the array of n matches.


⁵*+31ÆḍÆNB>/  Helper link. Argument: k

⁵*            Yield 10**k.
  +31         Yield 10**k + 31.
     Æḍ       Count the proper divisors of 10**k + 31.
              This yields c = 1 if 10**k + 31 is prime, an integer c > 1 otherwise.
       ÆN     Yield the c-th prime.
              This yields q = 2 if 10**k + 31 is prime, a prime q > 2 otherwise.
         B    Binary; yield the array of q's digits in base 2.
          >/  Reduce by "greater than".
              This yields 1 if and only if the binary digits match the regex /10*/,
              i.e., iff q is a power of 2, i.e., iff 10**k + 31 is prime.


⁵*+31ÆạÆNB>/  Helper link. Argument: k

     Æ        Unrecognized token.
              The token, as well as all links to its left, are ignored.
       ÆN     Yield p, the k-th prime.
      ạ       Take the absolute difference of k and p, i.e., p - k.
         B    Binary; yield the array of (p - k)'s digits in base 2.
          >/  Reduce by "greater than".
              This yields 1 if and only if the binary digits match the regex /10*/,
              i.e., iff p - k is a power of 2.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 + 11 + 9² = 101 bytes

### 1, 2, 3, 14

```
.fP_+31^T
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.fP_%2B31%5ET&input=4&debug=0)

### 1, 2, 3, 15

```
.fsIl-e.fP_
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.fsIl-e.fP_&input=4&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 + 12 + 8² = 88 bytes

### 1, 2, 3, 14

```
ÆN_µæḟ2=
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm1/8oa2Hlz3cMd/IlsvwcLvy//8mAA)

### 1, 2, 3, 15

```
10*+31ÆP
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QQEvb2PBwWwCX4eF25f//TQA)

Comment: 1) It should output the nth term, not the first n terms 2) Hey, one of our snippets are almost the same! 3) Uhh... that `10` feels very long.

Comment: 1) Instead of outputting the n-th term, each program can independently output the first n terms.

Comment: Hm, so that would make my answer kind of have a smaller score.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sorry about the confusion, I've incorporated that into the main text for greater clarity (previously it was only under "additional rules")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11B + 10B + 7B² = 70

### 1, 2, 3, 14

```
⁵*+31ÆP
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41YtbWPDw20BXIaH25X///9vAgA)

### 1, 2, 3, 15

```
ạÆNBSỊ
1Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroWH2/ycgh/u7uIyPNyu/P//fxMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17+17+7² = 83

### 1, 2, 3, 14, ... (17 bytes)

```
0G:"`Q11qy^31+Zp~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38DdSikh0NCwsDLO2FA7qqDu/38TAA)

### 1, 2, 3, 15, ... (17 bytes)

```
0G:"`QtYqy-Bzq~p~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38DdSikhsCSysFLXqaqwrqDu/38TAA)

Both employ the similar scheme of `` 0G:"`Q `` to have a counter running up and returning when a condition has been met `n` times. The actual program then is fairly straightforward. The `15` variant has some filler (`~p~`) to minimise the Levenshtein distance, while the `14` program employs an `11qy` rather than `t10w` to match the other program better.

Shared part:

```
0      % Push counter (initially zero)
 G:"   % Loop `n` times
    `  % Do .... while true
     Q % Increment counter
```

Top program:

```
11q         % Push 10
   y        % Duplicate counter
    ^       % Power
     31+    % Add 31
        Zp  % isprime
          ~ % If not, implicitly continue to next iteration. 
            % Else, implicit display of counter.
```

Bottom program:

```
tYq         % Nth prime based on counter
   y-       % Duplicate counter, subtract from nth prime.
     Bzq    % Number of ones in binary presentation, minus one (only zero for powers of two).
        ~p~ % Filler, effectively a NOP.
            % If not zero, implicitly continue to next iteration
            % Else, implicitl display of counter.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 + 11 + 6<sup>2</sup> = <s>84</s> <s>69</s> 57 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

### 1, 2, 3, 14, ... (A107083)

```
Îµ>Ð°32<+p
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN@hrXaHJxzaYGxko13w/78JAA)

### 1, 2, 3, 15, ... (A221860)

```
Îµ>Ð<ØαD<&_
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN@hrXaHJ9gcnnFuo4uNWvz//yYA)

Both output the 1-based \$n\$th value.

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, since it does `½` (*increase `counter_variable` by 1 if the top of the stack is truthy*) implicitly after each iteration of `µ`-loops (*while `counter_variable` is not equal to \$a\$ yet, do ...*).

**Explanation:**

```python
Î            # Push 0 and the input
 µ           # While the counter_variable is not equal to the input yet:
  >          #  Increase the top by 1
   Ð         #  Triplicate it (which is our `k`)
    °32<+    #  Take 10 to the power `k`, and add 31
         p   #  Check if this is a prime
             #  (implicit: if it is a prime, increase the counter_variable by 1)
             # (implicitly output the top of the stack after the while-loop)

Î            # Push 0 and the input
 µ           # While the counter_variable is not equal to the input yet:
  >          #  Increase the top by 1
   Ð         #  Triplicate it (which is out `k`)
    <Ø       #  Get the 0-indexed k'th prime
      α      #  Get the absolute difference of this prime with the copied `k`
       D<&   #  Calculate `k` Bitwise-AND `k-1`
          _  #  And check if this is 0 (which means it's a power of 2)
             #  (implicit: if it is 0, increase the counter_variable by 1)
             # (implicitly output the top of the stack after the while-loop)
```